# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver while using Postgres

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I was using sql server in my spring boot application and then I moved to postgresql database as container using docker-compose file and implemented flyway in my application.

While running the `docker-compose up`, I am getting error related to sqlserver driver while I am not using sql server anywhere in my application

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.username=${db_user}
spring.datasource.password=${db_pass}

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${db_host}:5432/test
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate
```

**docker-compose.yml**

version: '2'

```
services:
  app:
    image: 'app:latest'
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: app
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - ENV=local
      - db_user=test
      - db_pass=test
      - dh_host=db
    ports:
      - "5050:8080"

  db:
    image: 'postgres:13.1-alpine'
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=test
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

is there anything that I am missing ?

Regards,

Comment: Please add your full `application.properties` and make sure you have refreshed you r whole aplication so that the new `application.properties` is available to the project. Flyway tries to connect to sqlserver (still?) so you might have a `flyway.datasource.url` or something in your setup. You are also using docker make sure you have rebuild the docker container (else you still will be using the old one).

Comment: Seems like the image from your app's Dockerfile may be cached and was referencing SQL Server drivers. What happens if you `docker-compose up --build`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yeah on running this, now I am getting issues related to postgresql which is quite understandable. so early image was still in cache and was being used ?